# ggplot: how to get a semi-transparent fill in a geom_rect with a color different from other geoms? fill=alpha() does not seem to work

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, alpha

I am trying to visualize surgical procedures before and after Covid-19:

[image]

As you can see, I have a `geom_rect()` colored differently than the `geom_point()`.

I want the blue `color` and `fill` in the `geom_rect()` to be semi-transparent, something like `fill = alpha("#2C77BF", .5))`. However, when using the script below, the `alpha`-part does not work.

How can I obtain the semi-transparency of `geom_rect()` for a color different from those specified for `geom_point()`?

```
ggplot(b,
       aes(x = cons_week, y = n, color = corona, fill = corona)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, shape = 21) +
  geom_smooth(se = F, method = lm, color = "black", show.legend = F) +
  geom_smooth(lty = 2, show.legend = F) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 167, xend = 167, y = 2.5, yend = 25), 
               color = "red", size = 1) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 30, 
                ymin = 0, ymax = 5),
            color = "#2C77BF", 
            fill = alpha("#2C77BF", .5)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "",
                     values = c("#8B3A62", "#6DBCC3"),
                     labels = c("COVID-19", "Normal"),
                     guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "",
                    values = alpha(c("#8B3A62", "#6DBCC3"), .25),
                    labels = c("COVID-19", "Normal"),
                    guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "",
                     breaks = seq(0, 210, 12)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "",
                     breaks = seq(0, 30, 5), limits = c(0, 30)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", 
                                    size = 17, 
                                    face="bold", 
                                    margin=ggplot2::margin(r=10)),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "white", size = 20),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey90"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey90"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.text=element_text(size=15))
```

Data

```
b <- structure(list(corona = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("C19", "Normal"
), class = "factor"), cons_week = c(185, 176, 190, 201, 184, 
170, 202, 179, 203, 178, 206, 208, 209, 193, 181, 168, 191, 171, 
192, 195, 186, 175, 187, 174, 207, 169, 205, 197, 200, 173, 204, 
199, 189, 180, 194, 188, 182, 177, 196, 183, 124, 111, 75, 148, 
27, 158, 1, 62, 11, 56, 57, 154, 141, 51, 112, 159, 116, 8, 126, 
121, 38, 9, 78, 122, 32, 63, 94, 129, 76, 43, 44, 103, 84, 89, 
92, 37, 67, 19, 73, 142), n = c(17L, 9L, 16L, 15L, 12L, 9L, 15L, 
17L, 11L, 12L, 15L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 13L, 11L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 11L, 
19L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 20L, 18L, 9L, 20L, 20L, 18L, 15L, 
10L, 13L, 14L, 21L, 13L, 23L, 18L, 14L, 7L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 14L, 
14L, 16L, 19L, 10L, 14L, 11L, 18L, 12L, 18L, 8L, 10L, 15L, 19L, 
21L, 17L, 11L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 15L, 13L, 17L, 18L, 15L, 14L, 
17L, 9L, 16L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 12L)), row.names = c(NA, -80L
), groups = structure(list(corona = structure(1:2, .Label = c("C19", 
"Normal"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(1:40, 41:80), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It is semi-transparent. Barely. The color-difference at 50% alpha is just not enough to see the nuances of the grid behind it. As a proof, add `geom_abline(slope=0.2)` *before* (below) `geom_rect`, then use `fill=alpha(.., 0.05)` and see that the alpha is working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@brunosm's answer is the way to solve this problem.  On [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)'s suggestion, I offer an answer that is more illustrative on the *reason why alpha doesn't seem to be working* when used with `geom_rect()`.  In truth, you can actually still use `geom_rect()`, although `annotate()` is the better option.

The answer lies in the inherent difference between `geom_rect()` and `annotate(geom="rect"...`.  which is that `geoms` draw things based on your `data=`, whereas `annotate()` does not.

Practically-speaking, it's easiest to see by demonstration.  You've already posted that you get a solid box when you use the following code below.  Please, note that `p` in this case is your entire plot code *without* the `geom_rect()` part:

```
p <- # your plot code entirely, but leave out geom_rect()
p + geom_rect(
  aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 30, ymin = 0, ymax = 5),
  color = "#2C77BF", fill = alpha("#2C77BF", .5))
```

That code gives you a solid blue rectangle and it looks like alpha did not work.  In reality, this is not quite the case, and the setting for alpha worked just fine.  Let's look at the following counterexample.  I'll do the same plot, but this time pass only the first observation in the dataset `b` to `geom_rect()`.  Note the different result:

```
p + geom_rect(data=b[1,],
  aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 30, ymin = 0, ymax = 5),
  color = "#2C77BF", fill = alpha("#2C77BF", .5))
```

[image]

It's working as expected!  This is because since `geom_rect()` is a `geom`, it is basing its draw method on the source data, which is in this case `b` in its entirety.  That means that *for every observation in `b`, `geom_rect()` is drawing a rectangle with alpha 0.5*.  In the end, the dark rectangle you are getting is a result of **overplotting** - in the case of your dataset, it is the result of drawing 80 rectangles with alpha = 0.5 on top of one another.

For even more illustration, note what happens when I pass two of the observations in `b` to `geom_rect()`:

```
p + geom_rect(data=b[1:2,],
  aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 30, ymin = 0, ymax = 5),
  color = "#2C77BF", fill = alpha("#2C77BF", .5))
```

[image]

Our rectangle is now a bit darker, since `ggplot` is drawing two rectangles in that same location.

Bottom line here is that `annotate()` takes the `data=` source out of the picture.  It means you can't annotate something that changes with your data, but if you had that situation, you would use `geom_rect()`.

I guess if you really want to do it this way with `geom_rect()`, there's no real problem to do it using `geom_rect(data=b[1,],...`... it's just probably not the *right* way to do it.  :)

Answer (score 6):

You are using the wrong function. Instead of geom_rect(), use annotate(), and put the alpha parameter inside. You also don't need aes().

```
(...) +
annotate(geom = "rect", xmin = 1, xmax = 30, 
                ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
            color = "#2C77BF", 
            fill = "#2C77BF", alpha = 0.5) +
(...)
```

Comment: Interesting, this works better than I expected it to. Incidentally, using `fill = "#2C77BF", alpha = 0.5` and `fill = alpha("#2C77BF", 0.5)` within `annotate` produce the same results, so it's not necessary to break `alpha=` out (though it does no harm).

Comment: Do you have any idea why `annotate` and `geom_rect` do colors so differently? I would not expect as stark contrast as this demonstrates.

Comment: I have no ideia :) I just remembered that I had this issue in the past and that I solved it using annotate. I'm used to put alpha outside, but you are right, it works inside as well.

Comment: @r2evans @brunosm The reason why you get a solid blue rectangle is because of overplotting.  `geom_rect()` is not correct to use here, yes, because it's taking the `xmin`, `xmax` aesthetics and using those to plot a `rect` *for every line in your dataset*!  You can see what's going on if you set `data=b[1,]` for `geom_rect()`.  It shows the "correct" rect, since it only plots one time.  `data=b[1:2,]` plots a slightly less transparent rect, because it's plotting twice... and so on.  By default, `geom_rect()` is using all 80 observations and ploting the same light colored rect... 80 times.  :)

Comment: @chemdork123, while brunosm's answer is certainly appropriate and fixes the *symptom*, I suggest that your comment is the true answer to why a geom's alpha does not behave the same as other geom's colors. Whether or not it's accepted, I think it's worth formalizing into an answer, if for no other reason than to break it out of a comment and into something more visible.

Comment: Added an answer to that effect.  Hopefully when someone has this question in the future they stumble upon some knowledge :)